# C++ constructor use and error?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this constructor

```
  Movie::Movie(char *&t, char *&d)
    {
       title = t;
       director = d;
    }
```

And in my main I have this:

```
   Movie * movies = new Movie[movie_size];//creating array of class "Movie" 
   Movie *movieone=new Movie("MovieTitle", "Director");
   movies[0]=movieone;
```

I get the following error:
no matching constructor for initialization of 'Movie'   main.cpp    line 14 C/C++ Problem

Isn't this correct, am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason to use `char*` as opposed to `std::string`?

Answer (score 2):

When you do this

```
Movie("MovieTitle", "Director");
```

you are passing string literals, which collapse to `const char*`. But your constructor takes non-const references to `char *`:

```
Movie::Movie(char *&t, char *&d) { .... }
```

You cannot bind non-const references to something that is `const`. But in actual fact, it doesn't look like you need references at all. Just take the pointers by value, but make them point to somewhing `const`:

```
Movie::Movie(const char* t, const char* d)
```

This requires that you change `title` and `director` to `const char*`, which makes sense if you want to make them point to string literals.

But note that the design relies on the caller passing string literals, or passing pointers to objects that will outlive the given `Movie` instance. This can be made to work, but is quite fragile. The safer option would be for the `Movie` to "own" the data, which can easily be done by giving it `std::string` member variables.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Too right. I added a sentence on that.

Answer (score 2):

As juanchopanza noted, the problem is that string literals get converted to type `const char*`, but your constructor only takes references to (non-const) `char*`, so it doesn't match.

A second point is that

```
Movie * movies = new Movie[movie_size];//creating array of class "Movie" 
Movie *movieone=new Movie("MovieTitle", "Director");
movies[0]=movieone;
```

won't work. The first line creates an array of `Movie`s (or tries to -- it won't work unless you have a default constructor), but the third line tries to set the first entry to a `Movie*`. Instead, you need to either a) create `movies` as an array holding pointers to `Movie`s, or b) copy `movieone` by saying

```
movies[0] = *movieone;
```

Either way, you need to be *very* careful with regard to object lifetimes with this approach; it would be very easy to either leak memory on the one hand, or keep references to non-existent objects on the other.

A much better approach is to not (directly) use any dynamic memory allocation at all. You can use standard library facilities which hide it all for you, like this:

```
class Movie
{
public:
    Movie(const std::string& title, const std::string& director)
        : _title(title), _director(director) {}

private:
    std::string _title;
    std::string _director;
};

// later...
std::vector<Movie> movies;
movies.push_back(Movie("Jurassic Park", "Steven Speilberg"));
```

This is safer, easier to use, and no less efficient than your approach above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using std::string for store strings in class. For arguments pass better use const string& or const char*.

Answer (score 0):

```
Movie *movieone=new Movie("MovieTitle", "Director");
```

Here you're passing `const char*`, but your constructor expects `char*`, so it doesn't match. Consider changing constructor to string or const char*